# Loop doesn't stop!? (C++ programming)

Tags: c++, c

I don't understand why my loop stops, i want the user to keep asking for a number and find its square root. If the user enters negative number THEN it should stop. please help, cant see my mixtake...

CODE:

```
int main (void)
{
    double number, calc;

    printf ("Enter a number to find its sqrt");

    while (1)
    {
        scanf ("%lf",&number);
        if (number > 0)
        {
            calc = sqrt(number);
            printf ("The sqrt of %lf is %lf", &number, &calc);
        }
        else
            printf ("Try again:\n");
    }
    return (0);
}
```

Not allowed to answer but, I see thanks you two!!
(Didnt  know i must exist loop)

Comment: what method do you think should be stopping, 1 is always true and there is no break.

Comment: A `while (1)` loop will never stop by itself. You need to exit it explicitly using `break`, `return`, `throw`, or perhaps `goto`

Comment: yeah @BrianBi goto is probably the answer that he should be learning ;)

Comment: For the sake of completeness, you know. Besides, I do not think that `goto` is categorically evil.

Comment: sure @BrianBi goto is a valuable tool, but if you don't understand what a stack frame is or how they change depending on local context then a naked goto is just a loaded gun

Answer (score 1):

You must exit the loop somewhere.

```
if(number < 0)
   break;
```

Alternatively you can do this (which would be better in this case):

```
number = 0;
while(number >= 0)
{
    ....
}
```